# In LWC, Clicking the button again does not respond

Tags: apex, lightning, lightning-web-components

In LWC, 
the button executes the JS method to call APEX.Class, 
and these processes are successfully completed, 
but there is no response when the button is clicked again.
Because I need to repeatedly get data from web services
**Surprisingly, if the web service call fails, I can click the button and execute JS and APEX.**

**1. This is the JS synchronization method**

```
/* eslint-disable no-console */
import { LightningElement, track, api} from 'lwc';
import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent'
import syncWeChatFans from '@salesforce/apex/cpcs_SyncWeChatFans.syncWeChatFans';


export default class SystemSetup extends LightningElement {
       @track showload = false;
}
syncBtn() {

    this.showload = true;
    syncWeChatFans({weChatAppId: 'wx9ef17895f36ae074',appId: 'FDDDDDDDDDDDLDG',appSecret: '2c02049bd3ce26d816ab32ce45a12592'})
        .then(result => {
            var responseCode = JSON.parse(result).code;
            var responseMsg = JSON.parse(result).msg;
            var responseData = JSON.parse(result).data;
            // this.totalFans = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(responseData))[0].total;
            // this.databaseTotalFans = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(responseData))[0].localTotal;
            if(responseCode === '0'){
                this.showload = false;
            }else{
                this.showload = false;
            }
        })
        .catch(error => {
            this.error = error;
        });
}
```

[image]

**2. This is the calling APEX.class(Web Services)**
[image: <code>enter image description here</code>]

**3. This is APEX**

```
public with sharing class cpcs_SyncWeChatFans {
    @AuraEnabled
    public static String syncWeChatFans(String weChatAppId,String appId,String appSecret) {

        System.debug(LoggingLevel.INFO, 'weChatAppId = ' + weChatAppId);
        System.debug(LoggingLevel.INFO, 'appId = ' + appId);
        System.debug(LoggingLevel.INFO, 'appSecret = ' + appSecret);

        Http http = new Http();
        HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
        // need change
        request.setEndpoint('https://qasp.yhcrm.cn/chatapi/wx/addWXUser');
        request.setMethod('POST');
        request.setheader('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        String reqBody = 'weChatAppId='+weChatAppId+'&appId='+appId+'&appSecret='+appSecret;

        // Set the body as a JSON object
        request.setBody(reqBody);
        HttpResponse response = http.send(request);

        if (response.getStatusCode() == 200) {
            responseVal responseBody = new responseVal();
            responseBody = (responseVal)JSON.deserialize(response.getBody(),responseVal.class);
            system.debug('responseBody = '+ responseBody);
            return JSON.serialize(responseBody);
        } else {
            System.debug(response.getBody());
            return response.getBody();
        }
    }

    // request value
    public class Body {
        public String weChatAppId;
        public String appId;
        public String appSecret;
    }

    // response value
    public class responseVal {
        public String code;
        public String msg;
        public String data;
    }
}
```

[image]

**4. This is html**

```
<td>
    <button class="slds-button" onclick={syncBtn} if:false={showload}> 同 步 
    </button>
    <lightning-avatar variant="circle" src="https://www.opet.com.tr/assets/images/loading_3.gif" initials="loading" fallback-icon-name="standard:person_account" alternative-text="loading" class="slds-m-right_small" if:true={showload}>
    </lightning-avatar>
</td>
```

[image]

Comment: Please post code snippets that we can copy and reproduce, it hard to code everything and reproduce.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its pictures instead of code snippet. WHich makes its hard to reproduce.

Comment: This problem has been solved, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are saying you are not getting response because you are not seeing any debug logs for server/apex.

This is because you have set `(Cacheable=true)` in Apex method.

That means, for the first time when method is invoked, it gets the data and is cached in client machine. There are 3 phases for cacheable:

1. If you invoke same method within `fresh` time limit (I think <30sec), it will directly fetch the data from cache. In this case, `you will not see apex debug`
2. If you invoke same method after fresh time limit and within `stale` time limit, it will immediately fetch data and show in `UI`, and also it will do a apex server call. Then if there is any data change, it will rerender UI again. Here you will see apex debug log.
3. If you invoke same method after `stale` time limit, it fetch the data from apex server and then rerender UI. Here you will see the apex debug log.

Comment: Great, thank you very much for your careful answers, which is very helpful for me to learn LWC.